# X509: Use -help for summary OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, self-signed

So I'm just trying to create a self signed cert using SSL. I've got to very last part but it won't complete. Every stage up to this point completed successfully. The command I'm trying to run is:

**openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in smime_test_user.csr -CA ca.crt -CAKey ca.key -set_serial 1 -out smime_test_user.crt -addtrust emailProtection -addreject clientAuth -addreject serverAuth -trustout**

However I just get the reponse;

**X509: Use -help for summary.**

Hope this all makes sense, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time

Comment: `-CAkey` should have k in lowercase, as listed in the help message

Comment: Always miss the obvious lol 
Thank you :)